# Rails 6 action cable chat app not working in firefox

Tags: firefox, websocket, chat, ruby-on-rails-6, actioncable

I made a Rails 6 app and added a private messaging feature in it using action cable. The chat works fine in chrome and edge but crashes in firefox. Upon investigation in firefox, I think whenever the 'send' button in the create message form is clicked, it seems it reloads the page, disconnecting the current subscription. It says in the terminal that the async job is performed successfully before it gets disconnected. The data (in received(data)) doesn't get console logged in the browser.

I thought I just need to prevent the page to reload once the 'send' button is clicked so I tried placing preventDefault in submit listener in both application.js and conversation_channel.js but didn't work. Also added onclick: false in the submit tag in message form but didn't work also. It's maybe my theory is wrong or maybe I executed the solution wrong.

Please tell me if you need more snippets of my code:

```
// this is app/javascript/channels/conversation_channel.js

import consumer from "./consumer"

document.addEventListener('turbolinks:load', () => {
    const conversation_element = document.getElementById('conversation-id');
    const conversation_id = Number(conversation_element.getAttribute('data-conversation-id'));
    const input_box = document.getElementById('message-input-box');
    const send_button = document.getElementById('send-btn');

    // for terminating other subscriptions when connected to a new subscription
    consumer.subscriptions.subscriptions.forEach(subs => {
        consumer.subscriptions.remove(subs);
    });

    consumer.subscriptions.create({ channel: "ConversationChannel", conversation_id: conversation_id }, {
        connected() {
          // Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server
          console.log('Connected to conversation id: ' + conversation_id);
          send_button.addEventListener('submit', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); });
        },
      
        disconnected() {
          // Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server
        },
      
        received(data) {
          // Called when there's incoming data on the websocket for this channel
          console.log(data);
          const el_user_id = document.getElementById('user-id');
          const user_id = Number(el_user_id.getAttribute('data-user-id'));
      
          let html;
          user_id === data.message.user_id ? html = data.own_message : html = data.not_own_message;
          
          const messageContainer = document.getElementById('messages-container');
          messageContainer.innerHTML += html;
      
          send_button.disabled = false;
          input_box.value = '';
        }
      });
});
```

this is where the user creates a message: app/views/messages/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_with scope: :message, url: item_conversation_messages_path(@conversation.item.id, @conversation.id), local: true, remote: true do |f| %>
    <div class="form-inline">
    <%= f.hidden_field :conversation_id, value: @conversation.id %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
        
    <%= f.text_field :content, placeholder: 'Type your message here...', class: 'form-control mr-2', id: 'message-input-box' %>
    <%= f.submit 'Send', id: 'send-btn', class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
        
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

It was pointed out by user even_progression in my reddit post https://www.reddit.com/r/rails/comments/ol9ygj/rails_6_action_cable_chat_app_not_working_in/ that I should check the local and remote options in the message form. I set local to false and remote to true and now it works. Idk yet why but I'm about to find out.